# Improve infix isNullOrEmpty

Tags: kotlin, infix-notation

I'm trying to improve some code by using infix :

Working code (but kinda ugly...) :

```
fun test (possibleEmptyString: String?, anotherPossibleEmptyString : String?): String {
    var test: String? = possibleEmptyString

    // If null or empty
    if(test!=null && !"".equals(test)) {
        test = anotherPossibleEmptyString
    }

    // If null or empty
    if(test!=null && !"".equals(test)) {
        test = "a known string"
    }

    return test!!
}
```

I want to improve readability like this :

```
fun test (possibleEmptyString: String?, anotherPossibleEmptyString : String?): String {
    return (possibleEmptyString orIfNullOrEmpty anotherPossibleEmptyString orIfNullOrEmpty "a known string")!!
}

infix fun String?.orIfNullOrEmpty(other: String?): String? {
    if (this != null && !"".equals(this)) {
        return this
    }

    return other
}
```

It works but i think it can be improve

Comment: It's a bit broad for Stack Overflow to ask how this code could be improved (on what front? Readability, memory, CPU cycles, size, ..?). You might want to check our sister site [CodeReview SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), make sure to check their rules first to tailor your question to their site.

Comment: @PaulStenne : I'll check this site, didn't knew it exists (shame on me !)

Comment: It's fine, I'm happy you'll get to discover it =D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be simplified like this:

```
infix fun String?.orIfNullOrEmpty(other: String?) = 
    takeUnless { it.isNullOrBlank() } ?: other
```

You take `this` (`takeUnless { }` can directly be invoked on `this` in this case, because extension) if it is not null or blank and `other` otherwise.

Note that Kotlin already has extensions for `isNullOrBlank` and similar.